# Is it possible (and does it make sense) to migrate vi/vim-related questions from other SO sites?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are lots of high-quality vi and vim questions on other Stack Exchange sites; for example, see [all the questions tagged vim on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vim).

Is it possible (and does it make sense) to migrate some of all of these to Vi and Vim?

Comment: See also: [If this site was launched, would Vim/Vi questions be migrated from SO?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/19563/38417)

Comment: This answer is the best way to solve this "problem": http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se/53#53

Answer (score 7):

Before any questions can be migrated here, we first have to be established as a reputable beta site, with no danger of being shut down.  We are currently a long way away from that.

Furthermore, by Stack Exchange policy, "better fit" is not a good enough reason to migrate a question.  It also needs to be off-topic on the original site.

Answer (score 7):

No, it makes zero sense. If the only purpose of this site is to serve as a repository for *existing* vi/vim questions, we'd be better off just closing it right now and telling folks to go to Stack Overflow.

Oh wait, **[we did that once already.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18066388#18066388)**

And y'all said "no, no, there are lots of non-programming questions about vi/vim that we need a place for! And Super User's icky! *Windows* people use that site. And no site exists for Unix users! None! We looked everywhere!"

Well, now's your chance to prove it. Either there's a reason for this site to exist *apart from the existing communities on Stack Exchange* that happen to use vi/vim, or we're all just wasting our time here. And aren't likely to waste more of it by shuffling around thousands of posts just for the hell of it.

If, by some miracle, this site actually graduates... [There is a documented process for negotiating the transfer of questions between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site).

Comment: To be fair, SU is a bit icky. Windows people use that site *and never tag their question properly*. That's a big part of why I gave it up: tags did not help me filter the questions I was interested in. (That problem doesn't apply to Emacs and Vi.)

Answer (score 6):

Certainly not while we're in private beta.

Also, in general, I believe questions over 60 days in age can no longer be migrated. Migration also causes various confusion (when checking your profile, "where did my question go?"; when clicking on a link, "why am I suddenly on a different site?!" or "Super User looks funny today").

It probably only makes sense to migrate new questions. But I doubt we want "automatic" migration paths set up from any of the big sites (at least not soon); it's really hard to convince them to only migrate *good* questions. It'd probably be OK from some of the smaller sites, e.g., Unix & Linux. One from Stack Overflow would be a disaster.

Comment: As for "migrating bad questions" -- I don't suppose this site will get so large traffic that would make dealing with bad questions troublesome.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it seems perfectly reasonable to "manually" migrate (i.e. copy) questions with unsatisfactory answers here.

Toward that end, my [first couple questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1060/kyle-strand?tab=questions) are "manual" migrations from SuperUser. I have quite a few more questions on SuperUser about Vim, but most of them already have what I'd consider satisfactory answers, so I have left them alone.

I have included cross-links between the old questions and the new.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to migrate questions  older than 90 days ... But re-asking useful questions that don't have an answer, or where you think it could have a better answer seems like a good idea to do.