# Discussion on migration of Vim questions from S.O

Tags: discussion, migration

For visibility, I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401013/9447571) on Meta Stack Overflow, proposing possibly migrating or encouraging users to ask questions about Vim here rather than there.

Please post answers if you have opinions about it. Either here or there is fine, depending on the group you'd like to reach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible (and does it make sense) to migrate vi/vim-related questions from other SO sites?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/is-it-possible-and-does-it-make-sense-to-migrate-vi-vim-related-questions-from)